# Stop setInterval() when the component is not displayed anymore

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting logs in a Nuxt component at constant interval of time from an API and then display it.

How can I stop the `setInterval` method when the component is not being shown (and restart it again when shown again) ?

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="text-center"> Logs </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>{{ logs }}</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logs: null,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(this.getLogs, 2000)
  },
  methods: {
    async getLogs() {
      console.log('getting logs')
      await this.$axios
        .get('logs/custom')
        .then((res) => (this.logs = res.data))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Move the `setInterval()` call into the `mounted()` lifecycle hook, and save it to a variable. In the `destroyed()` hook, call `clearInterval()` on the variable.

```
mounted() {
  this.interval = setInterval(this.getLogs, 2000)
},
data() {
  return {
    interval: null
  }
},
destroyed() {
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}
```

Comment: For the record, now `destroyed` is deprecated in favour of `unmounted`